# Flutter Appbar disappears when using Share

Tags: android, flutter, dart, share, appbar

When I use `Share.share` using Flutter share_plus package the app bar disappears and the content of the screen moves up...and it doesn't look very nice.

Simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        await Share.share('Some text');
      },
      child: const Text('Press me'),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot here]
Anyone knows why that happens?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: I face same issue, did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try **SafeArea** around Scaffold widget.

Comment: Just tried, it didn't work

Comment: you need to show some code, otherwise how will we know what is the problem?

Comment: I updated the post with a simple example, basically any use of Share.share causes this problem, no matter what the content of the screen is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out It works fine for me

```
     final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
     Share.share(shareURL,
       subject: title,
       sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
```

Comment: Hm, I tried but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still facing this issue. What worked for me was changing the **SystemUIMode** of my app inside the **main.dart** file (just before runApp) from this:

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);`

to this:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
            overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom, SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```